# Change Azure Standard Website location

Tags: azure, region, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to change Azure Standard Website location from East US to West US?
Is it possible to have different region website in same Standard website plan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you deploy a Web Site (with a `xxx.azurewebsites.net` namespace), it is associated with a specific region. To change region, you'd need to redeploy. Assuming you have a custom DNS name, you could redeploy with a completely new Web Site namespace and then remap your dns. Or... you can delete the current deployment, then grab the same namespace name when creating a new deployment in a different region.

You can have multiple Web Site deployments, each residing in whichever region you choose.